# How to retrieve the NAME of a button when it is clicked (android)

Tags: android, button

I have a RadioGroup that contains 4 RadioButtons. They all call the same method when clicked, I know how to get the text that is associated with the button, but I can't figure out how to get the NAME of the button that is selected.

Surely there must be a way?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you post the xml and java code you have so far for us to look at :)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this could help you on the way:

```
// radioGroup - you need to set this after creating the radiogroup, by findViewById done in the right place or just assigning upon creating it, depending on how you create your layouts.
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
String text = radioButton.getText().toString();
```

let me know if it works :) Always eager to learn and help !

Comment: This looked promising, but Eclipse told me to import the RadioGroup Widget, and then I got this complaint: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getCheckedRadioButtonId() from the type RadioGroup"

Comment: Instead of RadioGroup (which is a class name) you have to have an actual reference to your initialized RadioGroup.

Comment: Updated the answer according to jOntechs comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a switch case to do so and onclick just compare with view.getId() with each id of radiobutton and then do the need full fetching of button name.

Below is the sample code::

```
switch (checkedRadioButton) {
  case R.id.radiobutton1 : radioButtonSelected = "radiobutton1";
                                  break;
  case R.id.radiobutton2 : radioButtonSelected = "radiobutton2";
                              break;
  case R.id.radiobutton3 : radioButtonSelected = "radiobutton3";
                              break;
}
```

using the [LINK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RadioGroup1.html)

or you can use the below code also

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
Log.d("checked",radioButton.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Agarwal, I'm a bit confused by what you wrote above the code. Are you suggesting I use getid() to find out the id of the selected button and then compare it to the id of all buttons, using the switch case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `View.OnClickListener` for each `RadioButton`. Correct?

If so don't do that. The easiest way to handle `RadioButton` clicks is to use `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` instead.

In your `onCreate(...)` after the call to `setContentView(...)` find the `RadioGroup`...

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_rg);
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...);
```

The `onCheckedChanged` listener looks like this...

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
```

...so in the listener simply do the following...

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
String text = radioButton.getText();
```